Not able to run the bitbucket pipeline for deploying AWS Serverless sample app
I have a sample site that includes storing the index.html page on s3 and then using the API gateway to place the data inputted through the site to the dynamodb.
The code is working perfectly through the local machine but when I am running the same code and scripts through the bitbucket pipeline, I get this error every time.
    + serverless deploy --stage dev --verbose
Initializing
Deploying "sample-form-service" to stage "dev" (us-east-1)
Packaging
Excluding development dependencies for service package
Packaging
Retrieving AWS CloudFormation stack
Uploading
Uploading (42.44 MB)
Uploading CloudFormation file to S3
Uploading State file to S3
Uploading service sample-form-service.zip file to S3 (42.44 MB)
Updating AWS CloudFormation stack
  UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - sample-form-service-dev
  UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Function - SubmitFormLambdaFunction
  UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Function - GetFormLambdaFunction
  UPDATE_COMPLETE - AWS::Lambda::Function - SubmitFormLambdaFunction
  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Version - SubmitFormLambdaVersionoLD7IUMx3489kEjexP5qdHiaXRwhYjShVkJT6DKKI
  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Version - SubmitFormLambdaVersionoLD7IUMx3489kEjexP5qdHiaXRwhYjShVkJT6DKKI
  CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::Lambda::Version - SubmitFormLambdaVersionoLD7IUMx3489kEjexP5qdHiaXRwhYjShVkJT6DKKI
  UPDATE_COMPLETE - AWS::Lambda::Function - GetFormLambdaFunction
  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Version - GetFormLambdaVersionknN8NOAGxFJk7W0CqNsvffrsMk5EqoC9ELkzGoFCyQ
  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1722555029659
  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Version - GetFormLambdaVersionknN8NOAGxFJk7W0CqNsvffrsMk5EqoC9ELkzGoFCyQ
  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1722555029659
  CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::Lambda::Version - GetFormLambdaVersionknN8NOAGxFJk7W0CqNsvffrsMk5EqoC9ELkzGoFCyQ
  CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1722555029659
  UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - sample-form-service-dev
  DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1722554919958
  DELETE_SKIPPED - AWS::Lambda::Version - GetFormLambdaVersionNMamdUGGwTrUu1UF7gIIEFhTQ4oJG1Ir61DCVWUU
  DELETE_SKIPPED - AWS::Lambda::Version - SubmitFormLambdaVersionezdJ0sNx40ca7tsYdXrLnebxpJmOm1LdKKByJV0KwU
  DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1722554919958
  UPDATE_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - sample-form-service-dev
Fetching Service Information
Updating
Syncing directories to S3 buckets
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/./frontend: sync with bucket sample-form-service-dev-bucket (0%)
✖ Stack sample-form-service-dev failed to deploy (56s)
Finishing
✖ Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
    at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/serverless-s3-sync/index.js:302:22
    at <anonymous>


